# Triggering Maven profiles from Heroku configured Environment Variables

Tags: maven, heroku

I am trying to activate a profile in my maven pom as follows:-

```
    <profile>
        <id>test</id>
        </properties>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>env.SITE</name>
                <value>test</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
    </profile>
```

Now i am configuring heroku to have the environment variable SITE as follows:-

heroku config:add SITE=test.

I expect the environment variable to trigger the profile when code is pushed. However this is not happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config vars aren't currently available at compile time.  To change the Maven profile you will need to fork the [Heroku Java Buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-java).

Answer (score 13):

You can do this without a custom build pack.

Use this snippet in your pom.xml to display all properties available on Heroku and pick one that is not in your local: http://florianlr.wordpress.com/2012/04/24/16/

I used env.DYNO

```
    <profile>
        <id>heroku</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>env.DYNO</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
    ...
    </profile>
    ...
```

Works like a charm:)

Comment: Awesome. This should be accepted as a better answer. +1

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the maven profile using the environment variable `MAVEN_CUSTOM_OPTS`.

In your pom define maven profile activation to be based off the presence of a property. The below example uses the development profile if you specify it and defaults to production if you don't. [reference](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>production</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>!profile-development</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>development</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>profile-development</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

In Heroku set the `MAVEN_CUSTOM_OPTS` environment variable to use the profile. Note that this variable overrides the default option `-DskipTests`. [reference](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-java)

```
MAVEN_CUSTOM_OPTS=-DskipTests -Dprofile-development
```

In this example the production profile would not need `MAVEN_CUSTOM_OPTS` declared.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can introduce your own customized Maven `settings.xml` file, e.g. `heroku-settings.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

    <!-- activate by setting the MAVEN_SETTINGS_PATH config var to heroku-settings.xml in Heroku project settings tab.
    See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-a-custom-maven-settings-xml for more details.
     -->

    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>production</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Then activate the settings by setting the `MAVEN_SETTINGS_PATH` config var to `heroku-settings.xml` in Heroku project settings tab

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by adding Heroku Environment like below:

```
MAVEN_CUSTOM_OPTS=-P<profile_id>
```

and cut out "activation" tag from pom.xml.

Btw I don't know why this doesn't work (in Heroku I have ENVIRONMENT=test)

```
<profile>
  <id>test</id>
  <activation>
    <property>
      <name>env.ENVIRONMENT</name>
      <value>test</value>
    </property>
  </activation>
...
</profile>
```